# Trying to connect to SQL server EF error: 'The keyword 'Network Library' is not supported on this platform

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Full Error: *System.NotSupportedException: 'The keyword 'Network Library' is not supported on this platform, prefix the 'Data Source' with the protocol desired instead ('tcp:' for a TCP connection, or 'np:' for a Named Pipe connection).'*

Connection string: *"Data Source=tcp:88.88.88.88,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=ManagerZ;User ID=....;Password=....;"*

Im using ASP trying to connect to sql server db i host on my computer. I tried prefixing but i dont get it how i should do because i still get the error only using EF Core. On my desktop app with SqlClient everything works. Im also allowing tcp connections trough my firewall. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the fix had change the connection string:
"Data Source=88.88.888.8888,1433;Initial Catalog=ManagerZ; Integrated Security=False;User ID=....;Password=....;"

Answer (score 1):

Aniki your answer is correct but lets point out that in the new string you must remove "Network Library=DBMSSOCN" from the connection string.

Comment: Can you add this as a comment onto the respective answer rather than as a new answer?

Comment: @Otter thats not possible, because [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) needs reputation of 50 or more.